# Как работать с Entities в CoreData если свойство Codegen имеет значение Category/Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac, coredata

В XCode 8 появилась возможно частично или полностью генерировать классы (на языках Swift или Objective-C) для работы с CoreData. Если у свойства `Codegen` установлено значение `Manual/None`, то программист сам создаёт все классы для работы с CoreData, если оно имеет значение `Class Definition`, то система сама генерирует эти классы. И есть ещё третий вариант - `Category/Extension`, но нигде нет подробной информации, что даёт данная возможность. Могу лишь предположить, что от программиста требуется создать самостоятельно наследника от `NSManagedObject`, добавить свои методы, а всё необходимые свойства для работы с CoreData генерирует система. Является ли такой подход правильным или надо как-то по-другому работать с `Codegen = Category/Extension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по прочитанным мною статьям, действительно при `Codegen = Category/Extension` программист должен лишь создать класс-наследник `NSManagedObject`, добавить в него вспомогательные методы и свойства, а всё необходимое для представления данных из таблицы сгенерирует Xcode.